# error in your SQL syntax; [...] near '%+var+%' at line 1 Consulta LIKE MYSQL

Tags: c++

`
   UnicodeString user=usuario->Text;
   UnicodeString vidnom="select id_nombre from nombre where nombre like % "+user+" %";

UnicodeString contrasena;
   contrasena=log1->FieldValues["id_nombre"];`

I'm doing a school project in Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin
I want to make a query with wildcard "like" but the compiler throws me the error 
'%+a variable-code+%'
thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Show code in wider context, or complete

Comment: Apparently misspelled inserting parameters and only I change " by '
sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this code properly (formatted and corrected by me)

```
UnicodeString user=usuario->Text; 
UnicodeString vidnom="select id_nombre from nombre where nombre like '%"+user+"%'";

UnicodeString contrasena; 
contrasena=log1->FieldValues["id_nombre"];`
```

Then such concatenating SQL query can lead to SQL injection, or dependency on special characters in data.